# If Proxima Centauri goes supernova will it negatively affect the Earth?

Tags: star, astrophysics

Proxima Centauri is the closest star to the Earth (besides our Sun). If it went supernova, would such an event negatively affect the Earth? Can Proxima Centauri negatively affect the Earth in some other fashion?

Comment: Proxima Centauri is an M5 dwarf. It will never go supernova.

Comment: And what about the second part of the OP?

Comment: @fasterthanlight answered the first part (and thank you for getting this gist of my question) but not the second.

Comment: The simple answer to that is **no.** To affect the Earth significantly, it needs to pass very close (less than 100-1000 AU), which is virtually impossible.

Comment: @fasterthanlight Ok, great. Now I need one of you to combine your comments as an answer and then I can accept it.

Comment: See https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/supernove-distance/ for the effects of nearby supernovae

Comment: @planetmaker thx. I’ll check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing, Proxima Centauri **cannot go supernova.** It is only $0.12 M_\odot$, while core-collapse supernovae can only be triggered by stars that are more massive than $8 M_\odot$. Now the only exception here is if it undergoes a type Ia supernova, but this is very unrealistic because Proxima won't become a white dwarf in trillions of years and is not part of a binary system that is close enough to engage in mass transfer.

To answer your second question, the answer is also **no.**  To affect the Earth significantly, it needs to pass very close (less than 100-1000 AU), which is virtually impossible. Proxima will not approach closer than 3 light years from our Sun in the near future, so it absolutely has no effect on the Solar System. See [my answer regarding stellar collisions.](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/41001/31410)

Comment: As an ordinary star Proxima Centauri would have to get very close forits gravity to mess  up the solar system.  But if it could somehow turn into a supernova, a supernova at the distance of Proima Centauri would be very bad for life on Earth.

Comment: According to [this site](https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/safe-distance-from-a-supernova-earth/#:~:text=Bottom%20line%3A%20What's%20a%20safe,away%20from%20the%20exploding%20star), the safest distance from a supernova is at least 50 light years.